# How to find number of graphs for a given radius and diameter?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am looking for number of graphs on $n$ number of vertices with a given radius and diameter. Is there any software or program which gives all such graphs? Kindly help. It will be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From experience computing extremal and Ramsey numbers, I can promise that nauty (No AUTomorphisms, Yes?) will run orders of magnitude faster than sage and any other graph theory software.   nauty was initially written by McKay and Radzizowski to generate graphs **fast** to, among other things, compute $R(4,4) = 25$.  [McKay's page](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/) has resources and installation instructions.  If you load up the manual, you will see that on page 86, both the radius and diameter of the graphs to be generated can be specified.  Nauty runs in terminals and the command you want should look something like `./geng -n10 -Z5 -z3` to generate all graphs on 10 vertices with diameter 5 and radius 3.